# How to request focus to RecyclerView's not shown item

Tags: android

[image: Sample menu]

Please assume the device doesn't have any touch input. All controls done via keyboard navigation.

I'd like to show menu on keyboard event and will focus to certain item.

Current code works for rendered items.

```
    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            // menu button
            case 41:
                if (recyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // focus to 9th item
                    recyclerView.getChildAt(8).requestFocus();
                }
            default:
                return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
    }
```

If I want to focus to 20th item my code will break.

How can I focus to non-rendered item? RecyclerView should also scroll to position that holds 20th item.

Comment: use `scrollTo` to scroll to position and then try `requestFocus`. If i item not created it can not request focus right! .

Comment: How can I know index of item in Recyclerview? scrolltoposition doesn't always render same items. For example: focusing to 30th item while on focused on first item, it will render 21-30. If it currently focused 60th item, scrolling to 30 will result int 30-39.

Comment: What do you mean by `scrolltoposition doesn't always render same items` ? And 30th item have the index `30-1 = 29`  .

Comment: Lets assume there is 100 items and recyclerview will render 10 items at once. While focused on first item if I scrollto 30th item it will render 21-30th items on screen. However if it's focused on 60th item and if I scroll to 30 item, it will render 30-39th item on screen.

Comment: That can be calculated if you want to show focused item at middle  lets say or in the second scenarios you need to load `25-35` . This can be calculated by using `LayoutManager` check it out . Also can you add all this with question and explain a bit more about the expected result .

Answer (score 0):

First **scrollToPosition(index)** then **requestFocous(index)**

Comment: scrolltoposition doesn't always render same items. For example: focusing to 30th item while on focused on first item, it will render 21-30. If it currently focused 60th item, scrolling to 30 will result int 30-39.

Answer (score 0):

You can use smoothScrollTo

```
recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(currentPosition + 1);
```

currentPosition here is the RecyclerView visible position to scroll from.